# Can I deserialize JSON into an existing object with Json.Net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using [Newtonsofts Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize/deserialize some JSON data. From what I've gathered from the documentation the `Deserialize()` methods always return new objects. Is there any way to deserialize into an existing object? i.e. only overwriting the members that the JSON is deserializing?

Comment: the library has a DeserializeObject<T> method which is a generic method

Comment: Thanks for the superquick reply! Sorry for the duplicate. I did search but for different keywords.